# screen casting in windows like recordmydesktop

Tags: windows, screen-recorder

I would like to make some screen casts in windows. In linux I always use `recordmydesktop`. The big advantage with this software is that the encoding is done after capturing. Therefore, it does not consume much cpu during capturing. Also, it records on temporary files in `/tmp` not on RAM which is another bonus in particular for long trainings.

Is there such a thing available for windows FOR FREE?

Commercial **Camtasia Studio** and **Adobe Captivate** tend to do this perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [TechSmith's Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/) and it does exactly what you say. I have recorded hour plus sessions without an issue. They do have a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

The [ScreenRecorder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.utilityspotlight2.aspx) utility from Microsoft is ugly as hell but works if you're OK with proprietary [`WMV`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Video) format.  It's freeware.